# Change value in firebug and get with jQuery html()

Tags: jquery, firebug, html

I'm changing the value of a

```
<span></span>
```

using the firefox Firebug and then using

```
$("span").html();
```

But it is getting the changed value of the span, and not the original value that was generated when loading the page.

How can I get the original value of the span, and not the changed one by firebug?

I'm asking this only for security purpose, because i'm using this value in ajax to save to the database, but at now, it can be easily modified by a bad intentioned user using firebug or element inspection on chrome.

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything sent to the client-side can be changed, you can't rely on the security of your front-end. You'll have to make sure your server-side code is secure.

Even if you were to stop the user from changing the value of that span, they could still replicate your AJAX Request and change the parameters to send anything to the server that it will accept. You'll need to clean up the user's input on the receiving end and filter out anything you don't want.

If you're using SQL for the database transactions you should read-up on how to avoid SQL injection. As you mentioned a user could potentially try to send SQL to your database, which could be harmful. Here's an interesting [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) on the subject.

Comment: Nice reply. I'll check my PHP that is receiving the AJAX Request to avoid SQL Injection. Thanks!

Comment: @ThiagoRocha Sure thing! Can never be too careful with user input! Also, if this helped you could you accept as the answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the value changing, you need to compare the value to the original before you submit.

```
var spanMatches = function(original) {
    span === "Original Span" ? true : false;
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    // cache original value on domready
    var original =  $('span').html();
    // span value gets changed
    $('span').html('new value');

    $('form').submit(function(){
        if(spanMatches(original)){
            $.ajax(function(){
                // make sure you include `original` in data sent upstream
            });
        } else {
            alert('value has been changed');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but with this code, I cant storage a new span value because it only checks if the value has changed (user or the script itself), if not, execute the ajax, right?